# How to get lifecycleScope from Context or Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, coroutinescope

Is it possible to get lifecycle of passed `Application` or `Context`?

I need to run background service using Coroutines but already I do simple while(true) which doesn't support lifecycle of my app.

```
this.applicationContext?.let {
      CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
           while (true) {
                val fetchedLocation = LocationProvider.getLocationOrNull(it)
                fetchedLocation?.let { location = it }
                delay(1.toDuration(DurationUnit.MINUTES))
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Long-running background jobs cannot be done with coroutines. Coroutines will not continue running when your app is in the background. You need to use WorkManager or a Service.

Comment: Have a look at the section on *Lifecycle-aware components*: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle It has an example similar to what you're doing here. I'm assuming you want this coroutine running *only while your app/Activity/etc is running*! Also, you shouldn't do `while(true)` in a coroutine - use `while(isActive)` instead, that way it can be cancelled properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lifecycleScope` is an extension function on `LifecycleOwner`, it is defined like the following:

```
public val LifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope
    get() = lifecycle.coroutineScope
```

where `lifecycle` is an instance of `Lifecycle`.

Only `Activities` and `Fragments` implement `LifecycleOwner`, so the `lifecycleScope` instance can be retrieved only from `Activities` or `Fragments`.

You can create your own implementation of `LifecycleOwner` and retrieve an instance of `lifecycleScope` from it.

Comment: Not all Activities implement LifecycleOwner. I believe it must be ComponentActivity or a subtype. There is also a LifecycleService class provided by Jetpack (a Service that implements LifecycleOwner).